# Excel Function Help - Compare 2 Cells in Worksheet to 2 Cells in another worksheet, if they match, return value from a different column

Tags: excel, function, if-statement, vlookup, exact-match

I'm wondering if someone would be able to offer some advice on the best way to do this please:

**Data in Worksheet # 1**

```
Col A  | Col B | Col C
Part-1 |     8 |     2
Part-2 |     7 |     7           
Part-7 |     9 |     4
Part-8 |     2 |     6
```

**Data in Worksheet # 2**

```
Col A  | Col B | Col C
Part-1 |     8 | *Return value* (If Part-1 is found and 8 matches, return 2)         
Part-2 |     7 | *Return value*  
Part-3 |     8 | *Return value*
```

In `Worksheet#2` in Cell `C2` - I would like to check if the `Part-1` in `A1` is found in Col `A` in `Worksheet#1`. If it is, then I would also like to make sure the Number is `B2` in `Worksheet#2` matches the Qty in Col `B` next to the same part#, if both the Part# and Qty match, then i would like to copy across the value from the corresponding cell in Col `C` in `Worksheet#1`, to Col `C` in `Worksheet#2`. If it does not match, I would like it to return a `0`.

Comment: Can you reformat the question tables in your question? The spacing doesn't match up. Use two spaces at the end of the line to make a one line break and check out the preview window before you submit it.

Comment: If I have understood your question, then you can use a formula to compare two cells using `IF()` and then return the value of Col C if the data matches.

Comment: I have tried to reformat, would you please le me know how this looks please.

Comment: Also im wondering if you would be able to give some more info in the IF () statement i could use please?

Comment: `IF`, `COUNTIF` and `AND` functions should be all you need here.

Comment: I have tried If, And, Exact etc and i haven't had any luck for some reason, i have tried reading many forums and help menus and can't seem to figure out what im not doing right. Thanks for much for your reply, however wondering if there would be any chance you could share some more info on this pleas?

Comment: I did some formatting as an example, please complete or remove any mistakes yourself. The help button explains you all about formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, what you are doing is a lookup based on values in two columns. Looking at it from that angle, you can use a the [`SUMPRODUCT`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumproduct-function-HA102752853.aspx?CTT=1) function, which is supported in any version of Excel. Enter the following in `Sheet2`, cell `C2`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!$A:$A=$A2)*(Sheet1!$B:$B=$B2)*Sheet1!$C:$C)
```

Select and drag down the right-bottom corner of `C2` to complete column `C`.

This only works by virtue of the fact that the values in `Sheet1`, column `C`, are numbers. It breaks  if value pairs in column `A` and `B` of `Sheet1` occur multiple times, but you did not address that situation in your question in the first place.

For versions 2007 and up, you can use the more convenient function [`SUMIFS`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumifs-function-HA010047504.aspx) with basically the same approach:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!$C:$C,Sheet1!$A:$A,$A1,Sheet1!$B:$B,$B1)
```

---

Alternatively, you can use a combination of [`IF`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/if-function-HP010342586.aspx) and [`VLOOKUP`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/starter-help/vlookup-function-HP010343011.aspx?CTT=1) functions. A formula that will work for Excel 2007 or newer is the following:

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP($A1,Sheet1!$A:$C,2,FALSE)=$B1,VLOOKUP($A1,Sheet1!$A:$C,3,FALSE),0),0)
```

Older versions of Excel do not support `IFERROR`, but you can still use a similar approach as explained [here](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Iferror.html).

I have uploaded an example workbook [here](http://temp-share.com/show/dPf3apFNW), which includes an alternative method in column `D` of `Sheet2` as well.

Comment: Hi Reinier - Thank you so very much for your reply. This is my first time to a forum and am so gratful for the help from others you don't even know! Unfortunately i neglected to mention a very key point now im reading your msg, i have excel 2003 :( wondering therefore if there is any way to modify this to work in my version?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please make sure to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), especially the section [How do I ask questions here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) about voting for and accepting answers. I think the `SUMPRODUCT` approach should work with Excel 2003, did you try it? I uploaded a [version of the workbook save in old format](http://temp-share.com/show/Pf3Y1AbK20) but I have no way to verify it for 2003...

Answer (score 1):

Here is the a variation on Reinier's second approach in a form that will work in any version of Excel. You can use references to the specific data ranges, as I have done here, or to entire columns.

```
  =SUM((A2=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$5)*(Sheet2!B2=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$5)*Sheet1!$C$2:$C$5)
```

This is an array formula, so it needs to be entered with the <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> combination. It performs the same operation as the SUMPRODUCT. (There are several other ways to do this, such as using MATCH with INDEX or OFFSET.)